# how to resitrict user from accessing a folder in php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have searched it all around but couldn't find it all i want to know is i have a folder called temp like

->public_html

-->temp

now how do i restrict a user from accessing it from outside server like it gives an error when someone includes it in their php script? i want to do it through php not through .htaccess or apache i tried chmod but it restricts the whole website from the local server only. i have done the constant thing also but if someone knows the constant name then he can still extract the data.

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to grant local access but restrict remote access you should be able to use chmod and chown to do just that.

Comment: How do you 'inlcude the folder in a PHP script'? Normally, you'd protect a folder with .htaccess - PHP can't protect a folder unless it's just a virtual folder generated through PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by _"i have done the constant thing"_?

Comment: I don't understand either what you are trying but if you want to be able to include php files from a directory but you don't want them to be available via an url there are a number of solutions.. one of the simplest (but not php based also) would be to get that directory outside of the web root

Comment: Ok sorry my bad ok let me explain like we include a php script by adding a simple include('script.php') now a user can access any of the files if he adds include('url.com/temp/script.php') and the constant thing i am taking about is we add define('Script', TRUE); on the place where we will include the script and the script which we will be included will have that if(!defined('Script')){ echo "Go back"; } now all i want is that the local server can access all the files and if anyone goes nasty he is not allowed how can we do that? but i want it through php only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include a remote PHP file. If they have `allow_furl_open` and `allow_url_include` set to true and use `include('http://yoursite/temp/yourfile.php')`, then what gets included is the **output** of that PHP file. Not the PHP source itself.

So when you have a php file with the following contents:

```
<?php
    $password = "secret";
    echo "Test";
?>
```

And someone includes that file remotely, they'll only get "Test" back, which isn't valid PHP syntax. They won't be able to see the contents of the file, only what gets outputted. The file runs on the remote (or in this case your) server. Whoever includes it gets the output *after* execution on that server.

So you **don't** have to do anything like `if (!isset(some_magical_constant)) die("Go away!")`, that's just plain silly, but unfortunately I've seen it all over the web.

Comment: you mean like there is a mysql query goin on like:

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user", $con) or die(mysql_error());

$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
now no one can fetch the data from the $user array right?

Comment: Yes, your PHP code and data usually cannot be included or accessed from outside. However, it is not silly to exit PHP files that are supposed to only be executed in a controlled environment (likely included by index.php or similar). Depending on how code is written, it may do evil things when executed without it's controlled environment.

Comment: You're right, but if you need to rely on checks like that I think it's time for a total rewrite. Rather by someone else than the original programmer.

Answer (score 1):

htaccess, only way I know of... don't think it's possible with PHP

```
<Directory /public_html/temp>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an empty "index.html" file inside your "temp" folder. This prevents user from seeing the contents of that folder. Which basically makes it impossible for users to work around it.

As for including it in a script, people have to know what files are in it to use it in a script.